# Can't Install org Through Package Manager

Tags: org-mode, package, microsoft-windows

I'm trying to upgrade `org` in my setup by following the instructions [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#installing-via-elpa) but I don't see org listed as an option.  The instructions say to report it as a discrepancy but I'm thinking it's more likely something on my end since I haven't seen it there for a while and figure someone else would have reported by now.

I'm on Windows with Emacs 25.1.1.  I've tried emacs -q then `package-refresh-contents` and can see the other packages listed at http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/ but not `org`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open emacs in the default fundamental mode (not in an org file).
2. Run `M-x package-refresh`
3. Run `M-x package-install` `RET` `org` followed by spacebar then `RET`.

The extra space at the end of `org` was essential in my case.

In my vanilla emacs install, `package-install` wanted to offer autocorrect for the *org-edna* and *orgalist* packages, so the spacebar was required to get emacs to move past those and recognize the entry for the plain-old *org* package.

Answer (score 2):

Orgmode is such a large project that it has [its own repo](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html).

See this [discussion on /r/emacs](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5sx7j0/how_do_i_get_usepackage_to_ignore_the_bundled/) about installing a new version of Orgmode using `use-package`.

Comment: I added that repo as well and still don't have the option of `org` using `package-install`  however I do have the option of `org-plus-contrib`.  I also checked `list-packages` and can see two `org` entries, one from gnu and one from the org repo.

Comment: Can you not install the version from the `org` repo by hitting `i`, then `x` in the package menu?

Comment: I'm able to install by doing that, I don't get why it doesn't show up in `package-install`.  This is also causing errors because I'd like to add org to my init file using `use-package`

Comment: R.e. `use-package`, see the [`/r/emacs` thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5sx7j0/how_do_i_get_usepackage_to_ignore_the_bundled/ddixpr9/) I linked to. Apparently `(use-package org :ensure org-plus-contrib :pin org)` should work; haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Does the `package-install` issue persist if you call `package-list-packages` first? Might be a caching issue.

Comment: package-install only works for packages that aren't already installed. org mode is installed by default, so it will never show up for package-install. You can upgrade it to a newer version via package-list-packages.