# How to update Org-mode through Emacs' Package Manager?

Tags: org-mode, install

I have org-version 9.1.9 installed and am attempting to install the latest version 9.2.2

I followed the instructions on https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#installing-via-elpa.
On my system, M-x list-packages lists two "org":

```
org                9.2.2         available  gnu        Outline-based notes management and organizer
org                20190311      available  org        Outline-based notes management and organizer
```

I selected 9.2.2 and thought I installed it.
But after I restarted Emacs, the old version of org-mode was still installed:

```
M-x org-version 9.1.9
```

So I followed instructions on https://orgmode.org/index.html.
I tried:

```
M-x package-install RET org RET
```

But "org" is not listed.  Although many "org-*" are listed.

How to update Org-mode through Emacs' Package Manager?

UPDATE 1:

My attempt from emacs -Q:

```
M-x package-initialize
M-x org-version
Org mode version 9.1.9
```

Did not install version 9.2.2.

Restart emacs -Q.
Without M-x package-initialize:

```
M-x org-version
Org mode version 9.1.9
```

There is no ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org/ directory:

```
$ pwd
/home/wolfv/.emacs.d/elpa
$ cd org
bash: cd: org: No such file or directory
```

package-archives value is:

```
(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
 ("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
 ("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
Original value was 
(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
```

No /home/wolfv/.emacs.d/elpa/org9.1.9:

```
$ pwd
/home/wolfv/.emacs.d/elpa
$ ls org*
org-bullets-20171127.526:
org-bullets-autoloads.el  org-bullets.el  org-bullets.elc  org-bullets-pkg.el

org-category-capture-1.1.0:
org-category-capture-autoloads.el  org-category-capture.el  org-category-capture.elc  org-category-capture-pkg.el

org-download-0.1.0:
org-download-autoloads.el  org-download.el  org-download.elc  org-download-pkg.el

orgit-1.5.1:
orgit-autoloads.el  orgit.el  orgit.elc  orgit-pkg.el

org-mime-0.1.1:
org-mime-autoloads.el  org-mime.el  org-mime.elc  org-mime-pkg.el

org-plus-contrib-20180618:
COPYING            ob-lob.elc             org-archive.elc        org-habit.el                   org-src.el
dir                ob-lua.el              org-attach.el          org-habit.elc                  org-src.elc
etc                ob-lua.elc             org-attach.elc         org-id.el                      org-static-mathjax.el
ob-abc.el          ob-makefile.el         org-bbdb.el            org-id.elc                     org-static-mathjax.elc
ob-abc.elc         ob-makefile.elc        org-bbdb.elc           org-indent.el                  org-sudoku.el
ob-asymptote.el    ob-mathematica.el      org-bibtex.el          org-indent.elc                 org-sudoku.elc
ob-asymptote.elc   ob-mathematica.elc     org-bibtex.elc         org-index.el                   org-table.el
ob-awk.el          ob-mathomatic.el       org-bibtex-extras.el   org-index.elc                  org-table.elc
ob-awk.elc         ob-mathomatic.elc      org-bibtex-extras.elc  org-info.el                    orgtbl-sqlinsert.el
ob-calc.el         ob-matlab.el           org-bookmark.el        org-info.elc                   orgtbl-sqlinsert.elc
ob-calc.elc        ob-matlab.elc          org-bookmark.elc       org-inlinetask.el              org-timer.el
ob-C.el            ob-maxima.el           org-capture.el         org-inlinetask.elc             org-timer.elc
ob-C.elc           ob-maxima.elc          org-capture.elc        org-install.el                 org-toc.el
ob-clojure.el      ob-mscgen.el           orgcard.pdf            org-interactive-query.el       org-toc.elc
ob-clojure.elc     ob-mscgen.elc          org-checklist.el       org-interactive-query.elc      org-track.el
ob-comint.el       ob-ocaml.el            org-checklist.elc      org-invoice.el                 org-track.elc
ob-comint.elc      ob-ocaml.elc           org-choose.el          org-invoice.elc                org-velocity.el
ob-coq.el          ob-octave.el           org-choose.elc         org-irc.el                     org-velocity.elc
ob-coq.elc         ob-octave.elc          org-clock.el           org-irc.elc                    org-version.el
ob-core.el         ob-org.el              org-clock.elc          org-learn.el                   org-vm.el
ob-core.elc        ob-org.elc             org-collector.el       org-learn.elc                  org-vm.elc
ob-csharp.el       ob-oz.el               org-collector.elc      org-license.el                 org-w3m.el
ob-csharp.elc      ob-oz.elc              org-colview.el         org-license.elc                org-w3m.elc
ob-css.el          ob-perl.el             org-colview.elc        org-link-edit.el               org-wikinodes.el
ob-css.elc         ob-perl.elc            org-compat.el          org-link-edit.elc              org-wikinodes.elc
ob-ditaa.el        ob-picolisp.el         org-compat.elc         org-lint.el                    org-wl.el
ob-ditaa.elc       ob-picolisp.elc        org-contacts.el        org-lint.elc                   org-wl.elc
ob-dot.el          ob-plantuml.el         org-contacts.elc       org-list.el                    ox-ascii.el
ob-dot.elc         ob-plantuml.elc        org-contribdir.el      org-list.elc                   ox-ascii.elc
ob-ebnf.el         ob-processing.el       org-contribdir.elc     org-loaddefs.el                ox-beamer.el
ob-ebnf.elc        ob-processing.elc      org-crypt.el           org-mac-iCal.el                ox-beamer.elc
ob.el              ob-python.el           org-crypt.elc          org-mac-iCal.elc               ox-bibtex.el
ob.elc             ob-python.elc          org-ctags.el           org-mac-link.el                ox-bibtex.elc
ob-emacs-lisp.el   ob-ref.el              org-ctags.elc          org-mac-link.elc               ox-confluence.el
ob-emacs-lisp.elc  ob-ref.elc             org-datetree.el        org-macro.el                   ox-confluence.elc
ob-eukleides.el    ob-R.el                org-datetree.elc       org-macro.elc                  ox-deck.el
ob-eukleides.elc   ob-R.elc               org-depend.el          org-macs.el                    ox-deck.elc
ob-eval.el         ob-ruby.el             org-depend.elc         org-macs.elc                   ox.el
ob-eval.elc        ob-ruby.elc            org-docview.el         org-mairix.el                  ox.elc
ob-exp.el          ob-sass.el             org-docview.elc        org-mairix.elc                 ox-extra.el
ob-exp.elc         ob-sass.elc            org-drill.el           org-man.el                     ox-extra.elc
ob-fomus.el        ob-scheme.el           org-drill.elc          org-man.elc                    ox-freemind.el
ob-fomus.elc       ob-scheme.elc          org-duration.el        org-mew.el                     ox-freemind.elc
ob-forth.el        ob-sclang.el           org-duration.elc       org-mew.elc                    ox-groff.el
ob-forth.elc       ob-screen.el           org-effectiveness.el   org-mhe.el                     ox-groff.elc
ob-fortran.el      ob-screen.elc          org-effectiveness.elc  org-mhe.elc                    ox-html.el
ob-fortran.elc     ob-sed.el              org.el                 org-mobile.el                  ox-html.elc
ob-gnuplot.el      ob-sed.elc             org.elc                org-mobile.elc                 ox-icalendar.el
ob-gnuplot.elc     ob-shell.el            org-eldoc.el           org-mouse.el                   ox-icalendar.elc
ob-groovy.el       ob-shell.elc           org-eldoc.elc          org-mouse.elc                  ox-koma-letter.el
ob-groovy.elc      ob-shen.el             org-element.el         org-notify.el                  ox-koma-letter.elc
ob-haskell.el      ob-shen.elc            org-element.elc        org-notify.elc                 ox-latex.el
ob-haskell.elc     ob-sql.el              org-elisp-symbol.el    org-notmuch.el                 ox-latex.elc
ob-hledger.el      ob-sql.elc             org-elisp-symbol.elc   org-notmuch.elc                ox-man.el
ob-hledger.elc     ob-sqlite.el           org-entities.el        org-panel.el                   ox-man.elc
ob-io.el           ob-sqlite.elc          org-entities.elc       org-panel.elc                  ox-md.el
ob-io.elc          ob-stan.el             org-eshell.el          org-passwords.el               ox-md.elc
ob-java.el         ob-stan.elc            org-eshell.elc         org-passwords.elc              ox-odt.el
ob-java.elc        ob-stata.el            org-eval.el            org-pcomplete.el               ox-odt.elc
ob-J.el            ob-stata.elc           org-eval.elc           org-pcomplete.elc              ox-org.el
ob-J.elc           ob-table.el            org-eval-light.el      org-plot.el                    ox-org.elc
ob-js.el           ob-table.elc           org-eval-light.elc     org-plot.elc                   ox-publish.el
ob-js.elc          ob-tangle.el           org-eww.el             org-plus-contrib-autoloads.el  ox-publish.elc
ob-julia.el        ob-tangle.elc          org-eww.elc            org-plus-contrib-pkg.el        ox-rss.el
ob-julia.elc       ob-tcl.el              org-expiry.el          org-protocol.el                ox-rss.elc
ob-keys.el         ob-tcl.elc             org-expiry.elc         org-protocol.elc               ox-s5.el
ob-keys.elc        ob-vala.el             org-faces.el           org-registry.el                ox-s5.elc
ob-latex.el        ob-vala.elc            org-faces.elc          org-registry.elc               ox-taskjuggler.el
ob-latex.elc       ob-vbnet.el            org-feed.el            org-rmail.el                   ox-taskjuggler.elc
ob-ledger.el       ob-vbnet.elc           org-feed.elc           org-rmail.elc                  ox-texinfo.el
ob-ledger.elc      org                    org-footnote.el        org-screen.el                  ox-texinfo.elc
ob-lilypond.el     org-agenda.el          org-footnote.elc       org-screen.elc                 README_ELPA
ob-lilypond.elc    org-agenda.elc         org-git-link.el        org-screenshot.el
ob-lisp.el         org-annotate-file.el   org-git-link.elc       org-screenshot.elc
ob-lisp.elc        org-annotate-file.elc  org-gnus.el            org-secretary.el
ob-lob.el          org-archive.el         org-gnus.elc           org-secretary.elc

org-pomodoro-2.1.0:
org-pomodoro-autoloads.el  org-pomodoro.elc        org-pomodoro-pidgin.elc  resources
org-pomodoro.el            org-pomodoro-pidgin.el  org-pomodoro-pkg.el

org-projectile-1.1.0:
org-projectile-autoloads.el  org-projectile.el  org-projectile.elc  org-projectile-pkg.el
```

From list-packages:

```
org-plus-contrib is an available package.

     Status: Available from org -- Install
    Archive: org
    Version: 20190311
    Summary: Outline-based notes management and organizer
Required by: orgit-1.5.1, org-category-capture-1.1.0
Other versions: 20180618 (installed).
```

I clicked "Install", restarted Emacs, then

```
org-version
org mode version 9.1.9
```

The new org did not install.
Here are the *Message* buffer entries for the install and org-version:

```
Install package ‘org-plus-contrib-20190311’? y
Contacting host: orgmode.org:443
Type "q" to restore previous buffer.
Quit
...
Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /home/wolfv/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20180618/)
```

Comment: @Tobias, There is no ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org/ directory.  I am on Linux Fedora 29.  package-user-dir value is "~/.emacs.d/elpa".

Comment: @Tobias.  OK.  No /home/wolfv/.emacs.d/elpa/org9.1.9

Comment: There is no org-mode in list-packages.  I am running Spacemacs if that makes a difference.

Comment: org-plus-contrib Version: 20190311 did not install.

Comment: Dioes the messages buffer say anything about the installation?

Comment: Note that there is a duplicate of this question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31825/cant-install-org-through-package-manager. But, I don't know whether the answers there help in your case.

Comment: I just tried to install `org-20190225`. I get the following error message: `cl--assertion-failed: Assertion failed: (or (= (buffer-size tar-data-buffer) (buffer-size)) (eq tar-data-swapped (> (buffer-size tar-data-buffer) (buffer-size))))`. Do you also get that message?

Comment: My list-packages lists a different version of ‘org-plus-contrib-20190311’.  My *message* buffer entries are amended to the main question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91004/discussion-on-question-by-wolfv-how-to-update-org-mode-through-emacs-package-ma).