# How to update Org-mode via Package Manager?

Tags: org-mode, package, install

I have org-version 9.1.9 installed on Spacemacs and am attempting to install the latest org-version 9.2.6.
Install instructions are on https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#installing-via-elpa and https://orgmode.org/elpa.html.
I performed the following steps.

Check version installed:

```
M-x org-version
9.1.9
```

From [Can't Install org Through Package Manager](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31825/cant-install-org-through-package-manager) > Jeremy Roe.
Switch to default fundamental mode (not in an org file):

```
M-x fundamental-mode
```

Refresh and list packages:

```
M-x package-refresh-contents
M-x package-list-packages
```

Search list for org package:

```
C-s org
```

which listed two org entries; one from gnu and one from the org repo:

```
org 9.2.6     available gnu
org 20191007  available org
```

Install org from gnu repo:

```
org 9.2.6 RET org 9.2.6 RET Install RET
Install package 'org-9.2.6'? y
contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
```

Check version installed:

```
M-x org-version
9.1.9
```

Restart Emacs:

```
M-x org-version
9.1.9
M-x locate-library RET org
Library is file ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20190617/org.elc
```

The newer org-version did not install.
Same result when I attempted to install package 20191007 from org repo.

I posted a similar question on [How to update Org-mode through Emacs' Package Manager?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48287/how-to-update-org-mode-through-emacs-package-manager)

````
M-x spacemacs/describe-system-info
#### System Info :computer:
- OS: gnu/linux
- Emacs: 26.2
- Spacemacs: 0.200.13
- Spacemacs branch: master (rev. 8c0b8c344)
- Graphic display: t
- Distribution: spacemacs
- Editing style: vim
- Completion: ivy
- Layers:
```elisp
(javascript rust html csv c-c++ git shell spell-checking ivy emacs-lisp markdown org)
```
- System configuration features: XPM JPEG TIFF GIF PNG RSVG IMAGEMAGICK SOUND DBUS GSETTINGS GLIB NOTIFY ACL LIBSELINUX GNUTLS LIBXML2 FREETYPE M17N_FLT LIBOTF XFT ZLIB TOOLKIT_SCROLL_BARS GTK3 X11 XDBE XIM MODULES THREADS XWIDGETS LCMS2
````